# I am trying to send an email using Python, when I pass the last field as variable it does not send anything in the email

Tags: python, email, variables, web-scraping

```
 # Web scraping

 import urllib
 import smtplib
 from urllib.request import urlopen
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 def make_soup(url):
     thePage= urllib.request.urlopen(url)
     soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thePage, "html.parser")

    return soupdata


 soup = make_soup("http://www.met.gov.kw/?lang=eng")
      for record in soup.select('#newForecast'):
      information = record.text

content = information[48:440]
msg =  content
```

Here is the part of the code I am having problems with when i transfer the information stored in content to message and then pass it to the sendmail() function where the body message is supposed to go the email shows up as empty
Can you tell me what is going wrong?

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("yourEmail", "yourPassword")
server.sendmail("placeholder", "placeholder", msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Is the indent of your codes right?

Comment: yes the indenting is right

Comment: In the `for` loop, `information` will be set with the last `record.text`. Do you want it? Can you print the `content` before sending to check the `content`?

Comment: Yes I can print information content it works, just when I try to send that to the body of the email it prints a blank email

Comment: I see your problem. Content isn't only text. I write better a answer

Comment: Ohhh I see can you please show me your method

Comment: When i print content I get this :

Comment: Today : Partly cloudy to cloudy with light to moderate freshening gradually at times north easterly to northerly wind, with speed of 15 - 45 km/h causing raising dust with a chance for rain that might be thundery at timesTonight : Cloudy to partly cloudy with light to moderate freshening gradually at times easterly to south easterly wind, with speed of 15 - 40 km/h causing raising dust wit

Comment: I suggest you to replace your e-mail address with some placeholder in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `msg` is a raw string of content. For content of email you must use the MIME type ([Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipurpose_Internet_Mail_Extensions)).

In Python you can use the objects `MIMEText` (for only text) or `MIMEMultipart` (with attachment). It will convert your content to equivalent MIME format with the function `as_string()`. 
*Or you can build your own String with the MIME format. ;)*

Here is my correction for your code. That should work:

```
# import the object MIMEText
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
...
# build a instance of MIMEText from your content string
msg = MIMEText(content)
# Subject, From, To are the information, which the receiver will see
# It's no problem, if you use a fake address here. That's the way, how phishing mail or spam mail works
msg['Subject'] = 'Subject of my email'
msg['From'] = "placeholder"
msg['To'] = "placeholder"

...
# now use as_string() to convert your data to equivalent MIME format
# you can use `print msg.as_string()` to see how it is.
server.sendmail("placeholder", "placeholder", msg.as_string())
```

More examples [email examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)

Comment: It says MIMEText is not defined, what do i need to import for it to work?

Comment: Yes, you need to import it. Look at the first line. The `sendmail` function was false. I have corrected it

Comment: I added all of those this is the code now but I am still getting errors :(

Comment: content = information[48:440]
msg = MIMEText(content)
msg['Subject'] = 'Subject of my email'
msg['From'] = "talalkamran96@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = "talal_kamran@yahoo.com"

 
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("talalkamran96@gmail.com", "tellytat5642926")
server.sendmail("talalkamran96@gmail.com", "talal_kamran@yahoo.com", msg )
server.quit()

Comment: this is the error:

Talals-MacBook-Pro:desktop Talal$ python3 ez.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez.py", line 30, in <module>
    server.sendmail("talalkamran96@gmail.com", "talal_kamran@yahoo.com", msg )
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 872, in sendmail

Comment: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I have edited the function `server.sendmail`. Did you use it too?

Comment: Thanks a lot  julivico!! It works great now. Can you please explain to me why it was not working before? As I am new to this web scraping stuff

Comment: No problem Talal. I have edited my answer with the link to Wikipedia about MIME. You can read it again. It's may be easier to understand now.